# Get data from MySQL database table by specific field in url

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to PHP MySQL. Im developing a songbook site.

I want to create tables alphabetically in separate pages for each alphabet.

When a user click an alphabet in the menu it will direct to this page `site/publicsearch.php?browse=a`

This is the database :

```
| ID  |  TITLE        | ARTIST | CATEGORY | ALPHABET |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1  | Amazing love  | XXXXXX | Love     |     a    |
|  2  | Above all     | XXXXXX | Worship  |     a    |
|  3  | BXXXX         | XXXXXX | Love     |     b    |
|  4  | BXXXX         | XXXXXX | Worship  |     b    |
```

I pull the above database table like this : It works fine.

```
   <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

echo "Connected successfully";
exit();
}
    // Attempt select query execution

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lyrics_a";

    if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            echo "<table class='table'>";

                echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<th>#</th>";

                    echo "<th>Title</th>";

                    echo "<th>artist</th>";

                    echo "<th>cateogry</th>";

                echo "</tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td> <a href=publicsong.php?id=".$row['id'] . ">" . $row['eng_title'] . "</a> " . $row['tel_title'] . " </td>";

                    echo "<td>" . $row['artist'] . "</td>";

                    echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";

            }

            echo "</table>";

            // Close result set

            mysqli_free_result($result);

        } else{

            echo "No records matching your query were found.";

        }

    } else{

        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

    }



    // Close connection

    mysqli_close($link);

    ?>
```

I need separate alphabetical tables like this :

```
Alphabet "a" table results `site/publicsearch.php?browse=a` 

| ID  |  TITLE        | ARTIST | CATEGORY | ALPHABET |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1  | Amazing love  | XXXXXX | Love     |     a    |
|  2  | Above all     | XXXXXX | Worship  |     a    |

Alphabet "b" table results `site/publicsearch.php?browse=b` 

| ID  |  TITLE        | ARTIST | CATEGORY | ALPHABET |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  3  | BXXXX         | XXXXXX | Love     |     b    |
|  4  | BXXXX         | XXXXXX | Worship  |     b    |
```

I tried the below code doesn't work.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$alphabet = $_GET['alphabet'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lyrics` WHERE `alphabet`='" . $alphabet . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<br><br>";
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['title'];
echo $row['lyrics'];
echo $row['alphabet'];
}
?>
```

I'm newbie. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$alphabet = $_GET['alphabet'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lyrics` WHERE `alphabet`='" . $alphabet . "'";
```

replace with:

```
$alphabet = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['browse']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lyrics` WHERE `alphabet`= '" . $alphabet . "' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You propose the following URL: `publicsearch.php?browse=a`

But in your script you are using the request parameter `$_GET['alphabet']`

In addition, you don't need a separate column `alphabet` in your database, you can use [SQL's `LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
$letter = $_GET['browse'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `lyrics` WHERE title LIKE '{$letter}%'"
```